# Function to create Padovan sequence

Tags: r

I need to write a function that calculates the [Padovan sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence). The program must allow entering an integer that indicates the length of the sequence.

The expected sequence is: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 21, 28, 37, 49, 65, 86, 114, 151, ...

```
padovan <- function(n){
  p <- c(1,1,1)
  p <- c(p,p[n-2]+p[n-3])
  print(p)
}
padovan(50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code returns the sequence of padovan, I use a for loop.

```
##### Option 1
padovan <- function(k){
p<-c()
p[1]<-p[2]<-p[3]<-1
if(k < 4){return(p[1:k])}else{
for(n in 4:k){p[n]<-p[n-2]+p[n-3]}}
return(p)}

padovan(50)
[1]      1      1      1      2      2      3      4      5      7      9
[11]     12     16     21     28     37     49     65     86    114    151
[21]    200    265    351    465    616    816   1081   1432   1897   2513
[31]   3329   4410   5842   7739  10252  13581  17991  23833  31572  41824
[41]  55405  73396  97229 128801 170625 226030 299426 396655 525456 696081

##### Option 2
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('int padovanC(int x){
    if (x <= 3) return(1);
    return(padovanC(x-2) + padovanC(x-3));}')
sapply(1:50, padovanC)
```

Answer (score 2):

And here is a simple function for padovan_sequence

```
padovan_sequence <- function(n) {
   if (n < 1) stop("Please enter a positive number")
   p <- c(1, 1, 1)
   i = 4
   while(i <= n) {
    p <- c(p, p[i-2] + p[i-3])
    i = i +1
  }
  p[1:n]
}

padovan_sequence(50)
# [1]      1      1      1      2      2      3      4      5      7      9
#[11]     12     16     21     28     37     49     65     86    114    151
#[21]    200    265    351    465    616    816   1081   1432   1897   2513
#[31]   3329   4410   5842   7739  10252  13581  17991  23833  31572  41824
#[41]  55405  73396  97229 128801 170625 226030 299426 396655 525456 696081

padovan_sequence(1)
#[1] 1
padovan_sequence(2)
#[1] 1 1
padovan_sequence(-2)
#Error in padovan_sequence(-2) : Please enter a positive number
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using a recursive function definition for the Padovan sequence:

```
padovan <- function(x) {
    if (x == 1 | x == 2 | x == 3) return(1);
    return(padovan(x - 2) + padovan(x - 3));
}

sapply(1:50, padovan);
# [1]      1      1      1      2      2      3      4      5      7      9
#[11]     12     16     21     28     37     49     65     86    114    151
#[21]    200    265    351    465    616    816   1081   1432   1897   2513
#[31]   3329   4410   5842   7739  10252  13581  17991  23833  31572  41824
#[41]  55405  73396  97229 128801 170625 226030 299426 396655 525456 696081
```

---

As @Onyambu (thanks!) points out, we can make this even more succinct by defining a fully *vectorised* recursive function

```
padovan <- function(x) ifelse(x <= 2, 1, padovan(x - 2) + padovan(x - 3))
```

and then get the first 50 terms with

```
padovan(1:50)
```

Comment: or `x %in% 1:3` instead of `x == 1 | x == 2 | x == 3`?

Comment: `P = function(n) ifelse( n<=2 ,1,P(n-2)+P(n-3))` just realized you had posted this. Although in this case it might be slower. And also you do not need to use `sapply`. Everything is vectorized: `P(1:50)` will do the job.